# How do I export coefficients from a lm() object containing multiple lm()?

Tags: r, lm, coefficients

I have an object (S3; lm) that contains the linear regression outputs of 471 different models. I am trying to extract the standard error of a specific variable in each model but I'm unsure how to do so, can anyone help? Specifically, I want to extract the standard error for the variable "p" for EACH of the 471 models saved in the "fit" object.

```
varnames = names(merged1)[2036:2507]
          fit <- lapply(varnames, 
          FUN=function(p) lm(formula(paste("Dx ~ x + y + z + q +", p)),data=merged1))
names(fit) <- varnames
```

Thank you so much!

**Note**
Edited to reflect the anonymous function p, rather than x, as stated previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fit shown reproducibly in the Note at the end invoke `map_dfr` on that with `tidy` which will give a data frame containing coefficients and associated statistics.  We filter out the rows we want.

```
library(broom) # tidy
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # map_dfr

fit %>%
  map_dfr(tidy, .id = "variable") %>%
  filter(term == variable)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  variable term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 hp       hp     -0.0147    0.0147    -1.00  0.325  
2 drat     drat    1.21      1.50       0.812 0.424  
3 wt       wt     -3.64      1.04      -3.50  0.00160
4 qsec     qsec   -0.243     0.402     -0.604 0.551  
5 vs       vs     -0.634     1.90      -0.334 0.741  
6 am       am      1.93      1.34       1.44  0.161  
7 gear     gear    0.158     0.910      0.174 0.863  
8 carb     carb   -0.737     0.393     -1.88  0.0711
```

### Note

We compute fit reproducibly using mtcars which is built into R.

```
data <- mtcars
resp <- "mpg" # response
fixed <- c("cyl", "disp")  # always include these
varnames <- setdiff(names(data), c(resp, fixed)) # incl one at a time

fit <- Map(function(v) {
  fo <- reformulate(c(fixed, v), resp)
  lm(fo, data)
}, varnames)
```

### Updated

Significantly revised.

Comment: Hi G. Grothendieck, thank you kindly for the response. Your solution worked seamlessly, and you were correct in assuming that the anonymous function's argument was meant to be p. I will make edits accordingly to my question. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(fit,function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[p,][2],simplify = F)
```

subsetting to 2nd element serves standard error for a variable.

Comment: does "p" need to be in quotes here?

Comment: he used it in `paste` then I thought it was already a character object

Comment: Hi all, thank you so very much for your help! I'm having an issue running the code you provided:

> test = sapply(fit,function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[p,][2],simplify = F)
Error in summary(x)$coefficients[x, ] : invalid subscript type 'list'
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

Comment: could you try it in `lapply` ?

Comment: I ran it in lapply as well, the same error arose (please note in my example I use p but the actual variable in my code is x and I have accounted for this in the examples you've provided).
> test = lapply(fit,function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[x,][2])
Error in summary(x)$coefficients[x, ] : invalid subscript type 'list'
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

Comment: try 'x' in quotes.

Comment: I tried it in quotes, it still does not work.

Comment: if you're having trouble it would be great if you can provide a [mcve] ...

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for the link to the proper format for asking questions here on stack overflow. I will be sure to add minimal reproducible examples in the future, the answer from @G. Grothendieck works for my purposes.

Comment: The poster corrected the question so modify this answer to: `t(sapply(names(fit), function(nm) coef(summary(fit[[nm]]))[nm, ]))` or `t(sapply(fit, function(fit) tail(coef(summary(fit)), 1)))`